# Bundle install won't install Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, bundler

I'm working on an AMD x86_64 HP2000 laptop with Blackarch linux.

Nokogiri 1.6.6.2 will not `bundle install` and I cannot figure out why.

I have wiped about five times now just to see if I made an installation mistake but it's not the case.  The errors returned usually are "PERMISSION DENIED @ rb_sysopen".

I'm in the right folders and `bundle install` won't do a thing.

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION 2.4.5.1
RUBYVERSION 2.2.3
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
RUBY EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/ruby
GEM PATHS /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0                        
/home/archkiller/.gem/ruby
```

Comment: What did you try to install it ? (which commands ?)

Comment: gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2    and I have to gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2

Comment: Just tried to bundle install and said the Gemfile.lock needs write permissions

Comment: Do post more details, but not as an image - the actual text of the error is better.

Comment: I'm sure this is a common issue with nokogiri.   bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries, bundle.  did not work.  it says that /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin is not in my path...  is that ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: switching to pc to gice full outputs

Comment: GEM::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151107-7550-776kd2.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking i the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml version 2.6.21 or later is required
*** extconf.rb ailed ***
Could not create makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file or more details. 
extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in /usr/share/metasploit/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection

Comment: it also tells me sometimes that i dont have /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin in my path

Comment: When adding information, please add it to the question, not to a comment. That keeps the needed detail where it belongs, in the question itself, and helps us find it without having to read every comment in the question.

Comment: Add the output of `gem env` to your question please.